# Confusion with Object Oriented PHP

Tags: php, class, object

I am having a problem with my code. I have include two time the same class in a php page and when ever one works other doesnt work. My code might explain better then me.

```
<?php
    if($_POST['submit']){
        if(!class_exists('Some_Class'){
            include('Class.php');
            $obj = new Some_Class;
            $obj->Do_something_2();
            }
            unset($obj);
        }
?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">
        <?php 
            if(!class_exists('Some_Class')){
            include('Class.php');
            $obj = new Some_Class;
            $obj->Do_something_1();
            }
            unset($obj);
        ?>
            <input type="text" name=""/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The actual problem that is happening right now is that, i programmaticly add some html form elements in the form. And when i submit the form  i have a little checking done for post back and if the post back is set, then i again include the same class but perform other function in the class.So when at first when i refresh the page the first class included in the form works fine but when submitting the form then class included in checking post back work but not the one in the form. Hope i was able to lay down my problem, Do tell me is there any sort of problem in this approach of writing code.

Comment: Why don't you just include the class before any processing on the page?

Comment: You only need to include the class file once.

Comment: rather than performing tedious checks for the presence of a class, implement an `__autoload` function. http://ca3.php.net/autoload

Comment: Oh thank you very much, i included the Class once and it worked. Thanks for the support :D

Answer (score 6):

That's because `class_exists('Some_Class'))` is true the second time.  You have to move

```
$obj = new Some_Class;
$obj->Do_something_1();
```

outside of that conditional.

A better solution would be to `include_once` the class at the top of the page.

An even better solution would be to autoload it.

Note that even though you are using classes, this is still in a procedural style.

Comment: When i do that it gives me 
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Status in C:\xampp\htdocs\employee_monitoring_system\include\status.class.php on line 13

Comment: Also i m getting this error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function displayStatus() on a non-object
but i think including the class once would help. let me try once.

Comment: I meant when i moved 
$obj = new Some_Class;
$obj->Do_something_1(); outside of that conditional.

Comment: @ExplosionPills shhh... it's OK. He's gone now. \*pats your head\*

Answer (score 2):

You're checking two times if the class exists.

The second call should work, if you change it to:

```
    <?php 
        if(!class_exists('Some_Class')){
          include('Class.php');
        }

        $obj = new Some_Class;
        $obj->Do_something_1();
        unset($obj);
    ?>
```

(Setting the brackets like that, should be better for the first time, too)

You're not unsetting the class, just *one* object instance of the class.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function displayStatus() on a non-objectFatal... i m getting this error when trying your way

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the first time the class is defined it stays defined from that point onwards, also the include_once function can help you make sure you only include a document once

so what you would need to do is declare it once at the top of the document and then use it, for example:

```
<?php

if(!class_exists('Some_Class'){
    include_once('Class.php');

    }

if($_POST['submit']){            
        $obj = new Some_Class;
        $obj->Do_something_2();
        unset($obj);
    }
?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">
        <?php 
            $obj = new Some_Class;
            $obj->Do_something_1();
            unset($obj);
        ?>
            <input type="text" name=""/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

As a side you, it's important to note that on your original code you were unsetting the $obj variable outside the condition, that may lead to warnings as the $obj object might not exists some times as it's out of scope

Comment: Oh i didnt know about the Object scope , i will take that into consideration. Ne ways thank u for u help. It worked including the class once before any processing worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're creating a generic object each time. Use this:

```
<?php
include_once('Class.php');
$obj = new Some_Class;

if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $obj->Do_something_2();
}
?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <?php $obj->Do_something_1(); } ?>
            <input type="text" name=""/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```